# How to access button without knowing it's exact tag value in iOS?

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uibutton

I have a `UITableView` displaying some list of songs. Each `Cell` contain a button to play each cell song. When I click on one 1st cell's play button it should play the relevant cell song. If I click on another cell's play button it should stop the current playing song and start to play new cell's song.

My problem is how can I change the background image of clicked button using it's `tag` value.

I did it in this way

```
-(IBAction)PlayButtonClickinSearch:(id)sender
{
        audioPlayer=[Singleton sharedManager];
       UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
       if ([strWicharray isEqualToString:@"copyListOfItems"]) {
        strWhichSong=[copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
}

else if ([strWicharray isEqualToString:@"arrSongList"])
{
        strWhichSong=[arrSongList objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
}

strSongPlayingStatus=[audioPlayer searchPlay:strWhichSong :btn.tag];

if ([strSongPlayingStatus isEqualToString:@"playing"]) 
{
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}   

else if ([strSongPlayingStatus isEqualToString:@"stop"])
{
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}  
}
```

According to this code, I cannot reset the previosely clicked btn image when I click on another button in another cell. Is there any way to give change the background of the button which has this perticular `tag` value without giving an exact `tag` value.

like this

```
-(void)play :(int)tag
{  

    [btn(tag) setbackgroundImage :backImage];
}
```

Plz help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,here take one variable and assign previously selected button tag to that variable and then by using that value you can change the background.in below code `index` is an int type varible.

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:index];
    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your image name"]];
```

i hope it'l helps you.